# How can I install Fedora Linux on a MacBook Pro, Model A1150?

Tags: macbook-pro, install, unix, efi

I performed the following steps:

- Formatted a USB Flash Drive as: FAT32
- Copied the Fedora Live ISO image to: `/efi/boot/boot.iso`
- Copied [ISO 2 USB EFI Booter for Mac](http://www.mediafire.com/download/dpgorsfdkf6nn2c/ISO-2-USB+EFI-Booter+for+Mac+0.01+beta+-+Ubuntu+10.10+Live.zip) to: `/efi/boot/boot.efi`

I then inserted the USB Flash Drive into the MacBook Pro, pressing the  <kbd>option</kbd> key directly after turning it on. However, after selecting the disk to boot from, it only booted to a `grub` prompt.

What else do I need to boot this Fedora Live ISO image from a USB Flash Drive?

Comment: Your question might find a better answer over at the [UNIX & Linux SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Is your Mac a 2006 model? Does your optical (DVD) drive still work?

Comment: I guess so, would it be easier from that?  I do not have an empty dvd and it is already weekend here.

Comment: You have to put a @David somewhere in your comment, otherwise I will not be notified. When entering a comment, click on help for more information. From the menu bar under OS X, you can select "About this Mac" to get the year and screen size of your Mac. Generally, this is how Macs are identified. I prefer to use a RW DVD. It takes longer to write (burn) to a RW DVD, but they are reusable. Why did you not try the `dd` command to transfer the iso to the USB flash drive (stick)? Fedora's web site seems to indicate this as one possible method.

Comment: @David I bought a DVD-R, I wrote out the Fedora Live iso image but I could not boot it. I will try to write out the image with dd. And, I do not have an OS X running on the mac anymore.

Comment: @David I created a Fedora Live USB with dd. It does not show when starting the macbook with option pressed. The USB in the original question did show up at this stage, only it did not boot properly.

Answer (score 2):

I see in your question, per the second and third bullet points, you are attempting to boot the USB Flash Drive via UEFI.

From [4.2 UEFI boot of USB sticks](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_and_use_Live_USB#UEFI_boot_of_USB_sticks) on [How to create and use Live USB](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_and_use_Live_USB)

[image]

There are two MacBook Pro's with Model Number A1150, both having the Model Identifier MacBookPro1,1 with one of the following Processors, Intel Core Duo ([T2400](http://ark.intel.com/products/27235/Intel-Core-Duo-Processor-T2400-2M-Cache-1_83-GHz-667-MHz-FSB), [T2500](http://ark.intel.com/products/27236/Intel-Core-Duo-Processor-T2500-2M-Cache-2_00-GHz-667-MHz-FSB), [T2600](http://ark.intel.com/products/27237/Intel-Core-Duo-Processor-T2600-2M-Cache-2_16-GHz-667-MHz-FSB)) and Intel Core Duo ([T2500](http://ark.intel.com/products/27236/Intel-Core-Duo-Processor-T2500-2M-Cache-2_00-GHz-667-MHz-FSB), [T2600](http://ark.intel.com/products/27237/Intel-Core-Duo-Processor-T2600-2M-Cache-2_16-GHz-667-MHz-FSB)) on the 15" Glossy Display.

- **All three processors listed use a 32-bit Instruction Set.**

Therefore, since UEFI booting is only supported with the 64-bit release of Fedora and the MacBook Pro model A1150 has a 32-bit processor, you will need to download and burn a 32-bit version of Fedora to optical media (CD/DVD) and attempt to boot from it, if that too is even possible.

Comment: Why do you assume UEFI booting?

Comment: @David Anderson, The second and third bullet points in the question make for a logical assumption.

Comment: I suppose it is minor point, but UEFI did not exist until 2007 and the Mac is a 2006 model. But before I could install Windows on my 2006 iMac, I did have to do a firmware upgrade. @Gergely probably should check to see if the Mac's firmware is up to date. This might make a difference if Fedora offers a BIOS boot version.

Answer (score 1):

I have a (17-inch, early 2006) iMac which, like your Mac, is a 32 bit machine.  I downloaded the file `Fedora-Live-Workstation-i686-23-10.iso` from Fedora. This is the "*32-bit 1.3GB Live Image*" found at [this web page](https://getfedora.org/en/workstation/download/). Next, I burned the file to a RW DVD. I inserted the DVD in my Mac and held down the <kbd>option</kbd> key at startup. A DVD icon label "Windows" appeared. After selecting this icon, the computer attempted to boot to a live version of Fedora. **This failed**.

Next, I tried booting again and this time, when prompted, I selected "Troubleshooting". From the menu that next appeared, I selected "Test this media & start Fedora Live". This led to a successful boot of Fedora Live.

> Note: With Fedora, if I leave the computer unattended for a sufficient amount of time, the computer will go to sleep. To wake, I needed to tap the power button.

I did not attempt to install Fedora, but this option was presented to me.

> Note: This version of Fedora requires a BIOS to boot the computer. My computer was shipped without the ability to BIOS boot an operating systems. I needed to install a firmware update to enable this type of boot. The web site for such updates is "[About EFI and SMC firmware updates for Intel-based Mac computers](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201518)". To install such updates, requires OS X to be installed on your Mac.

**If you can not boot from this DVD, the solution may require applying a firmware update to your Mac.**